# How to cite others on the site

Tags: discussion

I'd like to add part [HRSE's](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/5635/hrse) answer to [Are monotonic and continuous preferences necessarily rational?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/are-monotonic-and-continuous-preferences-necessarily-rational?noredirect=1&lq=1) to my question of [What is a rational consumer?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17735/what-is-a-rational-consumer)

The reason why I'm asking, is due to potential rep i may receive which i technically do not deserve as I'm simply just copying and pasting part of his answer.

Im doing this to present a more complete picture on the topic in question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is in the same thread with the question, the topic already enjoys "a more complete picture".

In many cases, answers set out the canonical framework implied by the question, in order for the latter to be answered rigorously.

So in my opinion I do not see any need to copy-paste in the question, text that can be found one screen below.

In case you nevertheless want to proceed, don't worry about "misappropriating reputation": just clearly state "I am copying here part of HSRE's answer to be found below", and let voters decide.